# Open Settings, WiFi or Bluetooth page programmatically in iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to know how to Open Settings, WiFi or Bluetooth page programmatically in iOS 6.0.

I know there is a way to open setting page via custom URL but it is deprecated above iOS 5.1.

If there is any way to open the page directly,please let me know, Or provide some example code.

Any Help will be appreciated...

Comment: In older versions there was an URL schema as in iOS 5.1 but onwards removed now.

Comment: You already know the answer. No other way !

Answer (score 6):

At previous we are opening Setting Page from app Using Bellow line of Code:-

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

But now up to ios 5.1 it was working after that this one depreciated. and Till now Apple not providing the URL Schema for achieving this one in newer versions.

So now it is not possible to open default setting page in ios 6.

It is possible incase if the device is Jail Broken.